# Site Collection Import Issue using stsadm 

Tags: stsadm, import

I am having some issues with importing a PUblishing Site Collection using stsadm import.  THe Export didn't report any issues and in fact the import reported no issue.   When we try to access the root site collection url we get an error that a List doesn't exist with a correlation token reference.  I am not aware that this correlation token doesn't help us.  If we go to _layouts/viewlsts.aspx we can navigate to other sites witout issue.  Appears to be isolated to the collection level.    We are migrating from SP 2010 in both cases.

We also have no custom list definitions etc.   We do have one DVWP and a few CQWP on the page.
We did take a look at all the log files and haven't found anything.

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing the export & import using PowerShell?

Not sure what differences under the bonnet there are (if any), but I do know that the use of stsadm is deprecated in SharePoint 2010, and that the use of the management shell is now recommended as a replacement.

[Export a site, list, or document library (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx)

Comment: James,  I have to say that the power shell was the key on the import.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are [some issues](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/05/27/limitations-of-stsadm-o-export-import-related-to-publishing-sites.aspx) related to exporting / importing Publishing sites. Related, even saving a site as a template is disabled in SPD2010 for publishing sites.

What do the windows event log and ULS say?